# React rendering component before ComponentWillMount function / setState not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, setstate

I'm new to React and been struggling with my code and can't find what I'm doing wrong,

This is my code

```
export class MainPage extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pn_list : []
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/pn_info/over_30')
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState(
                {pn_list : response.data}
                )
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <SelectionMenu data={this.state.pn_list}/>
            </div>
            )
        };
    };

export default MainPage;
```

Basically my code is trying to render the `SelectionMenu` component before the `componentWillMount` finishes and I don't get why this is happening.

I tried to `console.log(this.state.pn_list)` after axios gets the response but it looks like the `setState` method is not updating it since it still logs the empty array.

Can you give me a help please?

Comment: This is completely expected. In fact, this has been such a common misconception that it contributed to the deprecation of `componentWillMount`.

Comment: Here is the documentation on the method: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html. Even though the method is **called** before the first render, you're using `axios` which is an asynchronous function and is **not** going to be complete by the time the render occurs.

Comment: Strategies for dealing with this are having a good initial state that represents the structure you will have after the data is fetched, and using [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to avoid rendering parts of your app that need the data before it's there.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `componentWillMount`, you should use `componentDidMount` for AJAX calls and populate state.

See more at: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#where-in-the-component-lifecycle-should-i-make-an-ajax-call

Comment: I don't think this will fix OP's issue; the axios call will only finish after the first render either way. The key is to not render the selection until `this.state.pn_list.length > 0`